# CMake link order and LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking

I'm attempting to link static libraries against test cases in a collaborative cmake project. My understanding is that I can use the [link_interface_multiplicity](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aLINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY) option to get around libraries being sometimes listed in the wrong order. What's the proper way to do this? I'm new to cmake and the docs are a bit daunting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`set_target_properties`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aset_target_properties) command for this.  For example, if you have two CMake targets, `MyLibA` and `MyLibB` (added via `add_library` calls), then you can set the `LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY` value to 3 for both of these by doing:

```
set_target_properties(MyLibA MyLibB PROPERTIES LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY 3)
```

Note that, while CMake commands, functions and macros are case-insensitive, variables *are* case-sensitive.  So you should always use `LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY`, `LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY_DEBUG`, `LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY_RELEASE`, etc., not `link_interface_multiplicity`.